# how to properly remove na_values that were read with an specific format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove specific `NA` format with `.dropna()` method from `pandas`, however when apply it, the method returns `None` object.

```
import pandas as pd

# importing data #
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',', na_values='NA')

# this is how the df looks like
df = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['NA', 4]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

# trying to drop NA
d= df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
```

This code returns a `None` object, expected output could look like this:

```
#   col1 col2
#0     2    4
```

How could I adjust this method?

Is there any simpler method to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Firstly replace **'NA'** values in your dataframe with actual **'NaN'** value by `replace()` method:

```
df=df.replace('NA',np.nan,regex=True)
```

Finally:

```
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    col1    col2
1   2       4.0
```

If you want exact same output that you mentioned in question then just use `reset_index()` method:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
    col1    col2
0   2       4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove records with string `'NA'`

```
df[~df.eq('NA').any(1)]

   col1 col2
1     2    4
```